# Excluding the application from recent app list on invoking finish() on Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a Service running in the background and at certain periods of time I create notifications with Notification and when the user clicks the notification, it opens an Activity (SurveyForm). I want to close that Activity when the user presses a button but leave the background Service running. I am calling the finish() method within the Activity but instead of closing it completely, Application is still present in the recent app list.

This is the code that creates the notification.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SurveyForm.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.SURVEY_ACTION);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Survey")
            .setTicker("New Survey")
            .setContentText("Please, answer the survey.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.survey_notification_icon)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setLights(0xff00ff00, 1000, 1000)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    mNotificationManager.notify(Constants.SURVEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

And the button code is the following:

```
bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
             //Close the notification
             nm.cancel(Constants.SURVEY_NOTIFICATION_ID);

             //Close this Activity
             finish();
        }
    });
```

**Update**

I have solved the problem by specifying the next property in the manifest file for the corresponding Activity.

> android:excludeFromRecents="true"

Comment: What do you mean by "minimize"? Android has no notion of "minimizing" an app.

Comment: @Karakuri by minimizing I mean  that the application is hidden but still appears in the recent apps list.

Comment: @Enrique, Please post the solution as answer to the question and then accept the same. It will help other people in better way and also shall earn you points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem by specifying the excludeFromRecents property in the manifest file for the corresponding Activity.

> android:excludeFromRecents="true"

Answer (score 0):

Call `finishAndRemoveTask()` instead of `finish()`